# Why are trait bounds for Send on trait implementations ignored?

Tags: generics, rust, dereference

Why are trait bounds for auto trait `Send` on trait implementations ignored?  ([Playground(1)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=59afbb47cdc4dabed291eda2782e928f))

```rust
trait IsSend {
    fn is_send(&self);
}

impl<T: Send> IsSend for T {
    fn is_send(&self) {}
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let i = std::rc::Rc::new(43);
    i.is_send(); // (!!) no compiler error although Rc<...> is not Send
    Ok(())
}
```

For example using a trait bound for a self defined trait (X) it works:
([Playground(2)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1dc6fff7f75d302563390711dcb239fc))

```rust
trait X {}

trait IsSend {
    fn is_send(&self);
}

impl<T: X> IsSend for T {
    fn is_send(&self) {}
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let i = std::rc::Rc::new(43);
    i.is_send(); // (ok) compiler error as Rc<...> does not implement X
    Ok(())
}
```

Even more confusing, using a trait bound on a function it works as expected: ([Playground(3)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fc246da5c5388f1d32606273906b4cf7))

```rust
fn is_send<T: Send>(_s: &T) {}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let i = std::rc::Rc::new(43);
    is_send(&i); // (ok) compiler as Rc<...> is not Send
    Ok(())
}
```

It looks like the auto trait `Send` (or auto traits in general) is treated specially. However, I have not found any documentation about this. Is this a bug or just my lack of understanding :-)?

Comment: `Rc<i32>` may not implement `IsSend`, but `i32` does, and dot notation invokes [auto-deref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules).

Comment: @trentcl Could you make a real answer out of that?

Comment: In an hour or two...

Comment: Oops, it looks a bit mean of me to post my "stolen" answer just a few seconds after @trentcl replied :(

Comment: @SOFe Not to worry! Saves me the trouble :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this slightly modified version of your playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cd0564d581b50e05d20e8f3dc54af7b5)

```
use std::any::TypeId;

trait IsSend {
    fn is_send(&self);    
}

impl<T: Send + 'static> IsSend for T {
    fn is_send(&self){
        println!("TypeId of T: {:?}", TypeId::of::<T>());
    }
}

fn main() -> Result<(),Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    println!("TypeId of i32: {:?}", TypeId::of::<i32>());
    println!("TypeId of Rc<i32>: {:?}", TypeId::of::<std::rc::Rc<i32>>());

     let i = std::rc::Rc::new(43);
     i.is_send(); // (!!) no compiler error although Rc is not Send
     Ok(())
}
```

And we have the result:

```
TypeId of i32: TypeId { t: 13431306602944299956 }
TypeId of Rc<i32>: TypeId { t: 1918842018359854094 }
TypeId of T: TypeId { t: 13431306602944299956 }
```

I changed:

- Added a few `println!` calls so that we can see the TypeId of the types
- Added a requirement `T: 'static`, due to `TypeId` constraints. This should not affect our answer, since both `Rc<i32>` and `i32` are `'static`.

It can be seen that `T` is resolved as `i32` instead of `Rc<i32>`. That is, `is_send` is called with `T = i32` rather than `T = Rc<i32>`.

This is because [`Rc<T>` implements `Deref<Target = T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html?search=#impl-Deref). When you call `i.is_send()`, it is actually equivalent to `(*i).is_send()`, and `*i` is an `i32`, which is a `Send`. The compiler attempts to perform dereferencing when you use the dot operator to call a method on a value until the type bounds are satisfied.

To show this, let's [try changing `Rc` to `Arc`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d86d7b38b3e8f15931d7c70e79523048), where `Arc` implements `Send`. You can see that `T` now has the same TypeId as `Arc<i32>` rather than `i32`. This is because `Arc` already satisfies the `T: Send` bound, and no further dereferencing is required.

```
use std::any::TypeId;
use std::sync::Arc;

trait IsSend {
    fn is_send(&self);    
}

impl<T: Send + 'static> IsSend for T {
    fn is_send(&self){
        println!("TypeId of T: {:?}", TypeId::of::<T>());
    }
}

fn main() -> Result<(),Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    println!("TypeId of i32: {:?}", TypeId::of::<i32>());
    println!("TypeId of Arc<i32>: {:?}", TypeId::of::<Arc<i32>>());

     let i = Arc::new(43);
     i.is_send(); // (!!) no compiler error although Rc is not Send
     Ok(())
}
```

```
TypeId of i32: TypeId { t: 13431306602944299956 }
TypeId of Arc<i32>: TypeId { t: 3504454246784010795 }
TypeId of T: TypeId { t: 3504454246784010795 }
```